# Dask jobqueue job killed due to permission

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-jobqueue

I'm trying to use Dask job-queue on our HPC system. And this is the code I'm using:

```py
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=2, memory='20GB', processes=1,
                       log_directory='logs',
                       death_timeout=6000, walltime='8:00:00',
                       shebang='#!/usr/bin/ bash')

cluster.scale(5)

from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(cluster)
```

After executing the code, I can use `squeue` to check for submitted jobs, and I can see 5 of them in running `R` state. But the job are killed after several second. In the `.err` files, I found this message:

```
slurmstepd-midway2-0354: error: execve(): /tmp/slurmd/job10469239/slurm_script: Permission denied
```

I'm very new to Dask and am not sure what's wrong. Any idea would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with an incorrect specification of shebang:

```py
# ...
                       shebang='#!/usr/bin/env bash')
# ...
```

Depending on your SLURM settings, you might also need to specify `queue` (the appropriate SLURM cluster partition).

In case there are problems in the future, you can inspect the script that `dask_jobqueue` submits using:

```py
print(cluster.job_script())
```